# Razor, ViewBag и несколько RadioButton

Tags: asp.net, razor

Доброго времени суток.

У меня имеется следующая модель:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Информация")]
    public virtual ManInfo ManInfo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Должность")]
    public string Post { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Рабочий отдел")]
    public virtual Departament Departament { get; set; }
}
public class Departament
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Название отдела")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Цели отдела")]
    public string[] Aims { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Сотрудники")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Организация", Description = "Организация, в состав которой входит отдел")]
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Я пытаюсь вызвать **PartialView**, где происходит создание этой модели и передать туда через **ViewBag** коллекцию **Departament** из бд.

```
    //
    .cs
    //
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.Departaments = db.Departaments.ToList();
        return PartialView("_CreateEmp");
    }
    //
    .cshtml
    //
@model Models.Employee

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Добавьте работника в каталог:</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManInfo.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManInfo.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManInfo.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManInfo.SecondName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManInfo.SecondName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManInfo.SecondName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManInfo.MiddleName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManInfo.MiddleName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManInfo.MiddleName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManInfo.BirthDay, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ManInfo.BirthDay, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManInfo.BirthDay, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <text>Определить в отдел:</text>
        @foreach (Models.Departament dep in ViewBag.Departaments)
        {
            @* Вот здесь у меня возникает проблема *@
        }
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Post, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Post, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Мне необходимо отобразить список из имеющихся Departament в виде RadioButton таким образом, чтобы была возможность выделения только одного единственного.

Ну и, если это возможно, желательно, чтобы это нормально "въелось" в создаваемую модель (т.е. чтобы не заиметь лишнего кода в httpost-методе, который принимает модель Employee)

Comment: а не проще ли отобразить отделы не в radioButton а в выпадающем списке используя встроенный хелпер `Dropdownlistfor`

Comment: @Ruslan_K В таком случае нужно пилить новую вьюмодель, где будут хранится коллекция SelectList? Или же я неправильно понял?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как посоветовал @Ruslan_K оформил с помощью DropDownList

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Organization", (ViewBag.Orgs as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>),
       new { @class = "form-control", id = "orglist", onchange = "changed(this.value)" })<br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @Html.DropDownList("Departament", new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "form-control", id = "deplist"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Departament, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```